# What and how is the best way to fade in/out when loading/switching scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class Scenes_Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float duration;
    public Image image;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ImageFade(image, 1, duration));
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
       
    }
 
    public IEnumerator ImageFade(
Image sr,
float endValue,
float duration)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        float startValue = sr.color.a;
        while (elapsedTime < duration)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            float newAlpha = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, elapsedTime / duration);
            sr.color = new Color(sr.color.r, sr.color.g, sr.color.b, newAlpha);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is to fade to 1 make it black screen when loading the new scene.
and then when the new scene has loaded to fade in back to 0.

the problem is that in this way it's just loading the new scene too fast and never fade.
this script is attached to object in the current loaded scene.

in the Editor > File > Build Settings... i added both scenes already.

In the New Scene i have just a Main Camera and Directional Light

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) in your class to make sure it also exists after a scene change.
It would also be better to not use a fixed duration but to check when the scene is actually done loading so it still works for more complex scenes.